# Is there any issue with this Python script i am using it through sikuli? its not giving me the correct time

Tags: python, sikuli

When I measure the time manually, it is less than the time that I got through this script:

```
import time import os

def getTimes():
    try:    
        times = []

        if(exists("1472205483589.png",60)):
            click("1472192774056.png")

        wait("1472040968178.png",10)
        click("1472036591623.png")
        click("1472036834091.png")
        click("1472036868986.png")

        if(exists("1472192829443.png",5)):
            click("1472192829443.png")



        u = time.time()
        click("1472539655695.png")
        wait("1472042542247.png",120)
        v = time.time()
        print("Open File to when views list appear Â (sec) : " , int(v-u))
        times.append(int(v-u))
        u = time.time()

        click("1472042542247.png")
        wait("1472108424071.png",120)

        mouseMove("1472108424071.png")

        wait("1472108486171.png",120)

        v = time.time()
        print("Opening view (sec) : ",int(v-u)) 
        times.append(int(v-u))
        u = time.time()
        click("1472109163884.png")
        wait("1472042181291.png",120)
        v = time.time()
        print("Clicking element (sec) : ", float(v-u))
        times.append(int(v-u))

        return times
    except FindFailed as ex:
        print("Failed. Navigator might have stopped working")
        if(exists("1472204045678.png",10)):
                click("1472204045678.png")
        return -1


file = open(r"C:\BSW\SikulixScripts\NavigatorAutoTesting\log.txt",'w') ret = getTimes() if (ret == -1):
    file.write("-1")
    exit() str = " ".join(str(x) for x in ret) file.write(str) file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using time.time(), you are actually returning a number of seconds--the difference between "the epoch" and now. (The epoch is the same as `gmtime(0)`). Instead, try using `datetime.now()` which will give you a datetime object. You can add and subtract datetime objects freely, resulting in a timedelta object as per the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime)

```
    u = datetime.now()
    click("1472539655695.png")
    wait("1472042542247.png",120)
    v = datetime.now()
    tdelta = v-u
    seconds = tdelta.total_seconds() #if you want the number of seconds as a floating point number... (available in Python 2.7 and up)
    times.append(seconds)
```

This should yield more accuracy for you.